# Overriding method shadows overloaded final version

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, overloading, abstract-class

I have the following code:

```
struct Abs {
    virtual void f(int x) = 0;
    virtual void f(double x) final { std::cout << 2; }
};

struct Sub: public Abs {
    void f(int x) final { std::cout << 1; }
};
```

`Abs` is an abstract class which comprises a pure member function `void f(int)` and its overloaded version `void f(double x)`, which is no longer pure and `final`. If I try to override `void f(int)` in the derived struct `Sub`, it shadows `void f(double)` and the following `main` function prints `1`, converting `1.01` to `int`:

```
int main() {
    Sub x = {};
    x.f(1.01);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I overcome this problem? Also, why does it work like that?

Comment: It works like that because the standard requires it to.   Look up the "hiding rule".    It's not only for classes - it is also for nested scopes.   The "fix" in your case is for class `Sub` to have a line `using Abs::f`, which has the effect of making both versions of `Abs::f()` candidates when calling when calling `f()` within context of `Sub`.

Comment: You can enclose argument into curly brackets and implicit conversion will be prohibited. This way you will know beforehand about narrowing double to int.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given `x.f(1.01);`, the name `f` is found in the scope of class `Sub`, then [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) stops; the scope of `Abs` won't be examined. Only `Sub::f` is put in overload set and then overload resolution is performed.

> ... name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined.

You can use [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition) to introduce the names of `Abs` into `Sub`, then `Abs::f` could be found and take part in overload resolution too.

```
struct Sub: public Abs {
    using Abs::f;
    void f(int x) final { std::cout << 1; }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the `using` clause into your derived class to pick all the overloads from the base class.

```
struct Abs {
    virtual void f(int x) = 0;
    virtual void f(double x) final {std::cout << 2;} 
};

struct Sub: public Abs {
    using Abs::f;   // << this one did the trick
    void f(int x) final { std::cout << 1; }
};

int main() {
    Sub x = {}; 
    x.f(1.01);
    return 0;
}
```